# How to update UI from model business logic?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata

Use case: a simple billing app.

When quantity **or** price change, the total should change.

I'm using DataBinding, how do I notify the UI that `total` changed?

Model:

```
class Detail(){
    private var _quantity = BigDecimal.ZERO
    private var _price = BigDecimal.ZERO
    private var _total = BigDecimal.ZERO

    var quantity : BigDecimal
    get() = _quantity
    set(value){
        _quantity = value
        compute()
    }

    //same boilerplate for price

   private fun compute(){
       total = price.mutiply(quantity)
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    var instance = Detail()

    fun addQuantity(){
         instance.quantity.add(1)
    }
    
    fun addPrice(){
         instance.price.add(1)
    }
```

View

```
    <button onClick="@{() -> viewModel.addQuantity()}"
    <button onClick="@{() -> viewModel.addPrice()}"
    <textview text="@{viewModel.instance.total}"/>
```

My first idea was to make a LiveData, but I couldn't find any documentation that tells it's a good idea to create LiveData properties in the Model. As far as I've read they should be in the ViewModel exclusively.

I tried it anyway, but found another problem. I could only make it responsive to 1 property, but it needs to response to 2 properties (both qty and price)

```
var quantity = MutableLiveData<BigDecimal>()
var price = MutableLiveData<BigDecimal>()

var total = Transformations.map(quantity){ ... } 
var total = Transformation.map(price){ ...} // Duplicate property!
```

What's the right approach?

In .net world you just invoked NotifyPropetyChanged() and the UI would know. I can't find an analogous logic in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the guideline from the codelabs by google for data binding.

[https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/)

In shorts, you can use the LiveData for updating the view. In this way in your viewmodel should be like this

```kotlin
private val _quantity = MutableLiveData("100")
val quantity = _quantity
```

the xml layout

```xml
<data>
   <variable
      name="viewmodel"
      type="myviewmodel.SimpleViewModel"/>
</data>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/quantity_text"
   android:text="@{viewmodel.quantity}"
/>
```

Add this to the activity level

```kotlin
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
```

Just follow the link example for the much more details

Answer (score 0):

In viewModel take instance as LiveData

```
val instance = MutableLiveData<Detail>()

fun addQuantity(){
     instance.value.quantity.add(1)
}

fun addPrice(){
     instance.value.price.add(1)
}
```

In Fragment/Activity make sure you add this line for binding

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
```

make sure you have this library to use `viewLifecycleOwner`

```
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your intuition was correct. `LiveData` are exclusive to `ViewModel` but not limited to `ViewModel`s. It's the MVVM architecture approach which recommends to have `LiveData` in `ViewModel`s.

Anyways, let's assume you've got two live data called `quantity` & `price`. Now if total is dependent on both these two live data then you can make it [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) and then observe on both properties to make sure, result is always reflected when both are available *(changed)*.

Example below is how you do it:

```
var quantity = MutableLiveData<BigDecimal>()
var price = MutableLiveData<BigDecimal>()

val total = MediatorLiveData<BigDecimal>().apply {
    var updatedQty = 0
    var updatedPrice = 0

    fun updateTotal() {
        this.value = updatedQty.times(updatedPrice)
    }

    addSource(quantity) { quantity ->
        updatedQty = quantity ?: 0
        updateTotal()
    }

    addSource(price) { price ->
        updatedPrice = price ?: 0
        updateTotal()
    }
}
```